# Detecting 2 touches in same time

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios6

everyone! I need to detect 2 touches on different image views in same time. So I need to start timer when user touch both image views in same time. And stop timer when touches is end. The image views are moving on screen. There are no problems when I use one image view. Have you any ideas?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    for (UITouch *touch in allTouches)
    for (UITouch *touch2 in allTouches)

    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        CGPoint location2 = [touch2 locationInView:touch2.view];

        if ([touchArea2.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:location2]) {
             touchArea2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TouchAreaTouched"];
        }
        if ([touchArea.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:location]) {
           touchArea.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TouchAreaTouched"];

            timerTouch = 10;
            touchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(randomVoid) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        } else if (![touchArea.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:location]){
            [touchTimer invalidate];
            touchTimer = nil;
        } }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    for (UITouch *touch in allTouches)
        for (UITouch *touch2 in allTouches)   {


            CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
            CGPoint location2 = [touch2 locationInView:touch2.view];


            if (![touchArea.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:location]){
                touchArea2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TouchArea"];
                touchArea.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TouchArea"];
                [touchTimer invalidate];
                touchTimer = nil;
            }
        }

}


-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    touchArea.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TouchArea"];
    [touchTimer invalidate];
}
```

Thanks for any help))

Comment: "two touches at the same time" - is one second delay "the same time"? What about 100ms? What about 1 minute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about this problem a lot and I find the way how to do that.
Here is my code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    for (UITouch *touch in allTouches)
        for (UITouch *touch2 in allTouches)



    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        CGPoint location2 = [touch2 locationInView:touch2.view];


        if ([touchArea2.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:location]) {
            touchArea2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TouchAreaTouched"];

        }

        if ([touchArea.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:location]) {
           touchArea.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TouchAreaTouched"];
            if ([touchArea2.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:location2]) {
                touchArea2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TouchAreaTouched"];
                            timerTouch = 10;
            touchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(randomVoid) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
            } }}
    }


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    for (UITouch *touch in allTouches)



          {
            CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
              if (![touchArea.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:location]&&![touchArea2.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:location]) {
                  touchArea.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TouchArea"];
                  touchArea2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TouchArea"];
                  [touchTimer invalidate];
              }

                 }
}


-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    touchArea.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TouchArea"];
    touchArea2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TouchArea"];

    [touchTimer invalidate];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and then the method:

```
gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
      if ([touch view] == firstimage    ) { // Do Something}
      if ([touch view] == secondimage    ) { // Do Something}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = nil;
    tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    tap.delegate = self;
    [view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{

}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

then you recognizer the location of two touches,and decide what you do ;

Comment: I tried that, but image views are animated. That's why I choose to use
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Comment: I am sorry than cannot help you ,then I think that when you use touch with event ,why do not use a clear view that is the supper view of the two imageView ,then you use recognizer the two touch by location;hope can help you